# How does an int instruction know which registers to use when it runs?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, system-calls, bios

I'm a student studying the Assembly Language(NASM) and I need some clarification on how the interrupt "function" or int knows which registers to "run". I have figured out that a statement of

```
mov ah, 0x0e
mov al, "A"
int 0x10
```

prints `A` and that `0x0e` and `A` (`0x41`) form the `ax` register like (`0x0e, 0x41`) but how does the int "function" know that `ax` register is suppose to "run" instead of `bx` or `cx`? Is it just because the statements for `ah` and `al` are above int `0x10`?

Comment: There's no automatic mechanism. The author of that BIOS function (in this case) _decided_ that they would accept arguments in `al`, and `ah`. There's documentation that lists what arguments the various functions expect and return arguments, and where.

Comment: The answer is convention.

Comment: `int` itself is just a glorified `call` via a table. It does not do anything, it's the invoked handler that does. That is by default code in your BIOS. You can imagine that looks something like `cmp ah, 0x0e; je print_char` and `print_char` then looks at `al`. As such it does not matter where or how the registers got loaded as long as the proper values are in there.

Answer (score 5):

The `int` instruction doesn't actually do any printing. What it does, is jumping to a different piece of code. *That* code does the printing, and taking a function number in AH (and an argument in other registers depending on the function) was a *software* design choice on the part of the IBM PC BIOS authors.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_interrupt_call

---

To be specific, `int 0x10` does exactly this (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/intn:into:int3:int1):

1. push FLAGS onto the stack
2. disable interrupts and single step mode (controlled by bits in FLAGS)
3. push full segmented address of the next instruction onto the stack (return address)
4. read full segmented address (4 bytes) from RAM at position [0x10*4]=[64]. Note, that `0x10` here is the operand you provided to `int`.  This is an index into the IVT, Interrupt Vector Table, an array of logical seg:off addresses.
5. jump to that address

Only CS, IP, FLAGS, and SP registers are modified. All other registers stay as they are, and the target code can examine them. It is the target code, who decides what registers mean what. When the code is done, it performs `iret` (interrupt return) instruction, which does the opposite of `int` and jumps back to your program.

The target code is most likely a part of BIOS, although it can also be a part of a video adapter ROM.

You can also write a new address at the position [64], and redirect the `int 0x10` to your own code. You have to write an offset word at [64], and a code segment word at [64+2]=[66].